# Calculus/Complex Numbers exercise question.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be an increasing function in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(-1)>0$. 
Let $z=\frac{f(-1)f(0)}{2}+ \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{f(1)}i$ with $|z|=\frac{z}{2}(1-\sqrt{3}i)$.

Show that:
i) $f(-1)f(0)f(1)=8$

ii) $2Re(z)=|z|$
iii) $f(-1)<2<f(1)$

iv)$ \exists$ $f^{-1}$ and $-1 < f^{-1}(\sqrt{|z|}) < 0 $

I'm ok with i, ii, iv but I'm having difficulty with number iii.
Any hint is gladly accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(-1)f(0)f(1) = 8$ and $f$ is increasing, can $f(-1) \ge 2$ be true? How about $f(1)\le 2$?

Comment: ah, so we see that these two statements for $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$ are untrue because they give $f(-1)f(0)f(1)$ not 8, which means that $f(-1)<2$ and $f(1)>2$.